# Single click on button not working but double click does the work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my html code

```
<form runat="server">
    Hello, i'm login page
    Enter Name   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="submit" value="PressMe" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("EnterLogin", "LoginForm") %>'" />
</form>
```

Here is my controller code

```
public class LoginFormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowLogin()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult EnterLogin()
    {
        ViewData["Name"] = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["txtName"]);
        return View("EnterLogin");
    }
}
```

On clicking **PressMe** button the expected output is to display Enter Login View but it doesn't.If i double click on the button then it works fine.
Any reason for single click not to work??

Comment: You are mixing webforms and MVC. If I were you I would try looking at a MVC starting tutorial.

Comment: so u mean onclick shouldnt be used in mvc?Any other way of calling onclick events for elements in mvc except posting forms

Comment: You should instead set the url to the controller post method in the form and use a standard submit button

Comment: but what if i have more than 1 buttons on the form?

Comment: And use @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username) and have a proper MVC ViewModel what you are doing here is mixing old web forms with MVC

Comment: If you have more buttons then in most cases you should seperate the posts in two seperate forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `submit` button submits the page. Consider using

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("EnterLogin", "LoginForm") %>'">PressMe</button>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="PressMe" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("EnterLogin", "LoginForm") %>'" />
```